# URL route in google maps changes when click on icon or when maps is swiped

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how URL route in google maps change when click on icon or when maps is swapped?

For example when you open https://www.google.com/maps/@-6.3866918,106.8292099,16.65z

then you swipe left, URL will change to https://www.google.com/maps/@-6.3866236,106.8274545,16.65z

The latitude and longitude changed.

And when you click on icon, for example in this link :
https://www.google.com/maps/@-25.3451011,131.033689,15.88z

you click on uluru national park, the URL will change to :
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Uluru-Kata+Tjuta+National+Park/@-25.3451011,131.033689,15.88z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x2b236c2c7ed3b881:0xdb2a86cd5fe91ae4!8m2!3d-25.3437788!4d131.0346517

Does anyone know how it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows you to change the URL without having to reload the page (I assume that is what you were wondering about). It would be done in this manner in pure JS:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "new title", "/new-relative-url");
```

However UI framworks like AngularJS and ReactJS (along with react-router) will allow you to easily create links that can do this.

If you were wondering how the url itself is generated, google maps uses a canvas to render the map, so it could find out what is the point on the map which is shown in the middle of the canvas.

Comment: I thank you for answering. And about canvas, could you give reference/demo/example about it?
I'm still new in this concept

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API will tell you all there is to know about html canvas..However for a beginners tutorial to get used to the idea I would recommend first looking through https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: I think this would be most relevant to what you were looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/A_basic_ray-caster